# unable to do backup for large amount of data in php script

Tags: php, backup, fatal-error

I have function that is able to backup and restore database. This function works perfectly when the database amount is small. However, when the data is in a large scale, it's unable to complete the backup process and error msg is given. This is the sample of error msg:

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 192151552) (tried to allocate 63963113 bytes) in C:\wamp\www\samfahEnterprise\processbackup.php on line 69
```

Below is the script that i use to do the backup process:

```
<?php
session_start();
// Include settings
include("config.php");
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Singapore");

set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '20000M');

 // Set the suffix of the backup filename
if ($table == '*') 
{
    $extname = 'all';
}else
{
    $extname = str_replace(",", "_", $table);
    $extname = str_replace(" ", "_", $extname);
}

// Generate the filename for the backup file
$filess = 'backup/dbbackup_' . date("d.m.Y_H_i_s") . '_' . $extname;

// Call the backup function for all tables in a DB
backup_tables($DBhost,$DBuser,$DBpass,$DBName,$table,$extname,$filess);

// Backup the table and save it to a sql file
function backup_tables($host,$user,$pass,$name,$tables,$bckextname,$filess)
{ 
    $link = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
    mysql_select_db($name,$link);
    $return = "";   

    // Get all of the tables
    if($tables == '*') {
        $tables = array();
        $result = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES');
        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
            $tables[] = $row[0];
        }
    } else {
        if (is_array($tables)) {
            $tables = explode(',', $tables);
        }
}

    // Cycle through each provided table
    foreach($tables as $table) 
    {
        $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM '.$table);
        $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);

        // First part of the output - remove the table
        $return .= 'DROP TABLE ' . $table . ';<|||||||>';

        // Second part of the output - create table
        $row2 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table));
        $return .= "\n\n" . $row2[1] . ";<|||||||>\n\n";

        // Third part of the output - insert values into new table
        for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
            {
                $return.= 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';
                for($j=0; $j<$num_fields; $j++) 
                {
                    $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
                    //$row[$j] = ereg_replace("\n","\\n",$row[$j]);
                    if (isset($row[$j]))
                    { 
                        $return .= '"' . $row[$j] . '"'; 
                    } else
                    { 
                        $return .= '""'; 
                    }
                    if ($j<($num_fields-1)) 
                    { 
                        $return.= ','; 
                    }
                }
                $return.= ");<|||||||>\n";
            }
        }
        $return.="\n\n\n";
    }

    // Save the sql file
    $handle = fopen($filess.'.sql','w+');
    fwrite($handle,$return);
    fclose($handle);



// Close MySQL Connection
mysql_close();
} 

$_SESSION['save'] = "<span style='color:#00FF00'>The backup has been created successfully.</span>";
echo "<script>window.location = 'utility.php';</script>";
?>
```

Comment: Does Your machine has 20GB RAM memory ??? WOW!

Comment: no..the memory_limit is based on the RAM? i nver knew that...i just simply increase the number only to see whether it works or not with larger no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use PHP for that. Even despite you actually *can* resolve this problem - this will not be a good idea since you'll have to handle your tables and records within them one by one. So you'll change memory size to long execution time. That will be:

- Read row from table
- Write it into dump file
- Free memory for this row

(for now, you're trying to gather all table data and then dump it into file, which is impossible to allocate in memory when DB is too large)

In MySQL there's [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) - special tool to create SQL dumps. Unless there's a reason that prevents you of using it - I suggest you to do it (and - if you want to use PHP there are `exec()` and similar functions)

Comment: erm..how to use this tool? how if i need to have a script that allow the user to do weekly backup on their system? can i do it in PHP?

Comment: You can. There are `exec()` and similar functions

Comment: hi, I have followed ur suggestion to use mysqldump to create the backup. The backup is successfully created. But another is that, i cant restore the file, can u help me to have a look? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331490/command-restore-mysql-db-backup-in-php]

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug it like this:

```
echo ini_get("memory_limit")."\n";
ini_set("memory_limit","1024M");
echo ini_get("memory_limit")."\n";
exit();
```

Propably You must set correct value.

Comment: Bad idea. No matter how much memory limit you'll set. In common case DB will always be bigger (since DB is stored on disk)

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo in this case Your solution seems to be better :)